# Checking if user is authorized in React Reactor 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using a YouTube tutorial to learn React. They are using an older version of `react-router-dom`. I have been able to figure out how to use `v6` in simple stuff but now I am at `PrivateRoutes`. I can't seem to figure out what to change.

```
# /src/reducers/auth.js

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

```
# /src/reducers/index.js
mport { combineReducers } from "redux";
import leads from './leads';
import errors from './errors';
import messages from "./messages";
import auth from "./auth";

export default combineReducers({
    leads,
    errors,
    messages,
    auth,
});
```

```
// /src/common/PrivateRoute.js

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = () =>  (
//    const { user } = useAuth;
    <Navigate to='/register' />
)

// const mapStateToProps = state => ({
//     auth: state.auth
// });

export default (PrivateRoute);
// export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

```
// App.js

import PrivateRoute from './common/PrivateRoute';

<Routes>
                                <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard/>} />
                                <Route path="/login" element={<PrivateRoute><Login/></PrivateRoute>} />
                                <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>} />
                            </Routes>
```

If I don't do anything but use a `Navigate` in the `PrivateRoute` it works. If I try using `({ children })` I get a lot of errors.

I tried to go through the `auth` example on reactor documentation but I think I might be too new to React to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**You can do it using react-router dom-v6. create a PrivateRoutes component and add in app.js and use it.**

```
 // App.js
 const App: FC = () => {
  const isAuthorized = useSelector<RootState>(({auth}) => auth.user, shallowEqual)
  return (
   <>
     <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
         {isAuthorized ? (
           <Route path='/*' element={<PrivateRoutes />} />
         ):(
           <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
         )}
         <Route path='error/*' element={<ErrorsPage />} />
       </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>
   </>
 );
}
       
// /src/common/PrivateRoute.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = () =>  (
  const DashboardPage = lazy(() => import('../pages/Dashboard'))
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<DashboardPage />}>
      </Routes>
    );
)
export default (PrivateRoute)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there user authentication check here?

Comment: Yes, You can do it with authentication. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Let me know if it's working for you?

Comment: I might be totally wrong here, but would it be possible to pull in state from the files I have given in my question? I mean the `state` should already have whether logged in or not?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting auth variable from redux. You can get the auth user and update the state value and use it simply.

Comment: Would it be possible to give me an example on that? I can't seem to figure it out. I tried using `const useAuth = () => {
    return state.auth;
  };

function PrivateRoute ({ children }) {
    const auth = useAuth(children.state);
    return auth ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
    // <Navigate to='/register' />
}` but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246542/discussion-between-sid-and-sedhal).